# Purchasing music with two Apple accounts

Tags: ipod, music

I purchased some music from iTunes some time ago but recently made a new Apple account when I bought an iPod Touch 4Gen. Now the music purchased on the old account will not play on the iPod set up with the new account. Any idea why? Is this because of some type of permissions issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The music is assigned to the old account. In order to play that music you will have to sign into your iPod with your old accounts credentials. There may be a way to merge accounts but I am unaware of that. Apple does this to ensure everyone on different accounts actually has to purchase music separately hence more profit for Apple.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. So I guess my only option would be to switch accounts on my iPod or just start over with a new account. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes I believe those would be the only options. There may be a way to merge accou ts but I am sure its going to require calling Apple support if it is even possible.